# Defining different paths for different inputs in LINQ RX

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am learning LINQ RX and having a hard time understanding how to create handlers.

Let's say I have a `IObservable<Entity> source`, that provides a stream of entities. Now I want to define different strategies for processing those `Entity` objects depending on its `Entity.Group` property. I tried:

```
source.Where(e=> e.Group = "first").Do(e=> whatever).Subscribe();
```

And it works. The problem is when I add the second path:

```
source.Where(e=> e.Group == "first").Do(whateverWithFirst).Subscribe();
source.Where(e=> e.Group == "second").Do(whateverWithSecond).Subscribe();
```

Then things happen twice and I some exception related on how `source` is implemented.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: It seems like you are having issues with the difference between hot and cold Observables.

Comment: In this specific example, you're doing `whateverWithFirst` twice.

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: You need to let us know how `IObservable<Entity>` is created - particularly so we know if it is hot or cold. And you should let us know what the exception is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Observable.RefCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211664%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in order to share the subscription between both queries:

```
var publishedSource = source.Publish().RefCount();
publishedSource.Where(e=> e.Group == "first").Do(whateverWithFirst).Subscribe();
publishedSource.Where(e=> e.Group == "second").Do(whateverWithSecond).Subscribe();
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was assuming it was a cold source.

Comment: Change it to ``source.Publish().RefCount()`` Publish returns an IConnectableObservable that you have to call ``Connect`` and ``Disconnect`` on. The RefCount method adds reference counting semantics so that Connect is called on the first subscribe and Disconnect is called on the last unsubscription.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229126(v=vs.103).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211664(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: That's true, I forgot about RefCount() anyway. That's what 4 weeks away from work do to you :-)

Comment: Just to be clear... it doesn't matter if the source observable is hot or cold when you're using `RefCount`. The only thing that matters is whether a value yields itself between the first and nth subscription. Therefore, `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).StartWith(0)` will not work "correctly" with `RefCount`. `RefCount` causes the underlying observable to go hot as soon as it receives it's first subscriber.